# Stripe Node js charge a customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

All I am trying to do is charge a customer like this:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_5uwvjas5uFYUCZN5d3YdAT19");

stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 1000,
 currency: "usd",
 customer: "cus_112121212", // CUSTOMER ID
 destination: {
          account: "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
      },
}).then(function(charge) {
 // asynchronously called
});
```

According to the documentation:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create
This should be possible,
Yet i get the error:

```
there was an issue Error: No such token: cus_111212122112
```

Am I reading the docs wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The documentation states "The ID of an *existing* customer that will be charged in this request". The error message is a bit strange, mentioning a *token*, but are you sure there's an existing customer with that ID in your test account?

Comment: Does the Customer you are passing on this request exist on your account? Usually that kind of error happens when you are trying to charge a Customer with that id doesn't exist.

Comment: The id is valid in my test data yes. @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review Firestripe example since it’s in Node js.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

If that doesn’t help, confirm that customer have a source attached to it.  If not, then you can’t charge that customer.